# How to bind ComboBoxItem header to the sibling ListView's items count of Combobox control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

Why my first item of Combobox display nothing? Anything wrong with my binding?

xaml:

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="SettingsContextMenuItems" Type="system:Object">
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding ElementName=MainDataGrid, Path=Items.Count}"/>
      <MenuItem Header="TESTA"/>
      <MenuItem Header="TESTB"/>
    </x:Array>
      </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource SettingsContextMenuItems}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
      <ListView x:Name="MainDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Test> testList;

        public ObservableCollection<Test> TestList
        {
            get { return testList; }
            set { testList = value; }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            TestList = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
            TestList.Add(new Test() { Name = "a" });
            TestList.Add(new Test() { Name = "b" });
            TestList.Add(new Test() { Name = "c" });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a ObservableCollection in your viewmodel with the item list and bind it to your combobox?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. This is not the real scenario, the real scenario is much more complex. I just abstract the code and repro the issue.

Comment: I think it's the same. Instead of creating an array in xaml, make it a ObservableCollection in your view model and bind it to your combo. Unless there's something else in your real case I don't understand...

Comment: Sorry, the code may misleading you. Actually, the Path in binding is "Path=GroupedColumns.Count", the GroupedColumns.Count is a readonly property which provided by 3rd party datagrid control.

Comment: Now i understand. But i don't think you can bind like that in an x:Array. It expects an specific type for the items, and the system:object trick is not going to work. Anyway, i feel the ObservableCollection suggestion is still valid. You just have to create a property and in the get section return "GroupedCollumns.Count" and add that property to your ObservableCollection of MenuItems..think it should work just fine

Comment: Try adding `Mode=OneWay` to `<MenuItem Header="{Binding ElementName=MainDataGrid, Path=Items.Count}"/>` and let me know if it makes any difference.

Comment: @user2946329 thanks for your reply, but it not works.

Comment: Allen4tech did you tried my suggestion? Want some sample code to start with?

Comment: @Pikoh sorry, I didn't get your point, could you please provide some code snippet? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already resolved the issue. Though I don't know why binding in Array doesn't work, putting all the MenuItems into the ComboBox's Items property instead of assign ItemsSource could resolve the problem.

Thanks all the guys replied.

Answer (score 0):

Although i've just read you finally managed to solve your problem, i'm gonna explain the solution i proposed in the coments.

First, we create a ObservableCollection to feed the combobox

```
private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> menuItems;

public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuItems
{
    get { return menuItems; }
    set { menuItems = value; }
}
```

Then in the constructor, we initialize the values like this.

```
MenuItem a = new MenuItem();
a.Header = MainDataGrid.Items.Count;
MenuItem b = new MenuItem();
b.Header = "TESTA";
MenuItem c = new MenuItem();
c.Header = "TESTB";
MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
MenuItems.Add(a);
MenuItems.Add(b);
MenuItems.Add(c);
```

And finally,we bind this collection to the combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"/>
```

This is just to show you the idea. In your real case it maybe has to be tweaked a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to put any controls code in my ViewModel.